# Laravel 5.2.41 - error message strange behaviour - {{ $error); ?>

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've got strange behaviour with my laravel 5.2.41 app.

With commented code it shows messages correctly:

[image]

BUT without commented part it shows:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Did you named correctly a file ? It looks like code is not parsing, try change filename to your_file_name.blade.php

Comment: It's named:  create.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

try instead of `@if($errors->any())`

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
```

Comment: The same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
@forelse($users as $user)
   <li>{{$user}}</li>
@empty
  There is no user
@endforelse
```

Try this

Comment: The same behaviour.